# How to different call custom function record struct parameter in delphi?

Tags: function, delphi, struct

Unit 1 source:

```
type cha = record
 data1 : string;
 data2 : String;
end;

type Tchadata = Array of cha;

var
 A : Tchardata;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 GetData(A);
end;
```

Unit2 source:

```
type cha = record
 data1 : string;
 data2 : String;
end;

type Tchadata = Array of cha;

procedure Getdata(var Data : Tchadata);
begin

end;
```

This is my Delphi code. But complied...

> [Error] Unit1.pas: Types of actual and formal var parameters must be
>   identical

Why?

I don't well english. Sorry. 
Why it can not be compiled?

Comment: Try to remove the var parameter in the `Getdata` procedure and make it a value parameter

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the types are defined identically, they are distinct. Hence the error message.

You should define the record exactly once. It looks like it should be defined in `Unit2`, and imported into `Unit1`.

**Unit2**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  cha = record
    data1 : string;
    data2 : String;
  end;

  Tchadata = Array of cha;

procedure GetData(var Data : Tchadata);

implementation

procedure GetData(var Data : Tchadata);
begin
  // Populate Data
end;

end.
```

**Unit1**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Unit2; // imports types and the procedure

implementation

procedure Foo;
var
  Data: Tchadata;
begin
  GetData(Data);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks guy.. delphi noop :(